# Setting Environment Properties in PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables

I'm using AWS Beanstalk which allows me to set environment properties in the backend for my application container and retrieve theme as shown below:

```
echo get_cfg_var('aws.access_key');
echo get_cfg_var('aws.secret_key');
echo get_cfg_var('aws.param1');
echo get_cfg_var('aws.param2');
```

I'd like to set up a similar environment property locally, so that my password never reach my repository (I'm using git) - what is the best way to do this? php_ini? httpd.conf? How would I add the variable `param1 = 'password';`?

Cheers!

Comment: You should consider using SSH and `ssh-agent`.

Comment: by the way- this is for a mysql password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your php.ini add the lines.

```
aws.param1=whatever
aws.param2=whatever
```

Comment: I added this to the bottom of my php.ini, nothing happens when i do `echo get_cfg_var('aws.param1');`